# Can a hash table in c++ be used in a similar fashion to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm in a grade 12 computer science class and my teacher asked us to do an assignment involving basic function review to get comfortable with C++ once again since last year.

I'm recreating a Python program that uses a dictionary to hold a key value as a store product (ex. "Pasta") and the value of that key as a price (ex. 3.99) and uses that dictionary to create a shopping experience, that fills a cart and then checks out the items within the cart using the keys and their values.

However, I struggle to recreate that key-value storage a dictionary provides within C++.

I was wondering if a hash table would be an efficient solution? I've done some research on it and it appears promising but I don't know if it is a dead end.

Comment: std::unordered_map

Comment: Consider what a Python dictionary really is. It's a form of hashtable / hashmap. As DeiDei says, look into std:unordered_map. However, if you want to become more comfortable with lower level languages I suggest learning more about implementation / how things work underneath--specifically data structures. Python abstracts a LOT away.

Comment: " a dictionary provides within C++" - C++ oesn't provide anything called a dictionary.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: it's implicitly *"...recreate that key-value storage a dictionary provides [in python], within C++"*.

Comment: You could consider `std::unordered_map<std::string, double>`, but there are other options: e.g. you could store the integral number of cents in an `int` instead of having to deal with floating point rounding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard library has a container called [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) that stores key-value pairs and can quickly find the value given the key. It is implemented as a binary search tree so it searching has a logarithmic complexity.

There is also a container called [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which uses a hash table to store the elements with a constant average searching complexity.

Comment: "uses *something like* a hash table" - ummm... more specifically: a hash table ;-).

Comment: Not the expert in this, thanks for the clarification! The sites only mentioned buckets and hash values without specifically saying it's a hash table, so I wasn't completely sure.